# Spring MongoDb: Create indexes about unknown fields using bean classes

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm running against an issue I don't know whether it's possible to do.

I need to store a document class with known fields, but also I need to store it with unknown fields:

```
@Document
public class Metadata {

    @Indexed
    private String user;

    private Object metadata;
}
```

All these unknown fields are stored inside `metadata` field.

However, I know someone of them. I mean, inside `metadata` field there will be whichever thing user wants, but there're some fields application knows.

I'd like to know how to create indexes about these unknown-knowed `metadata` fields.

Example:

```
{ user: user, metadata: {known: v, unknown: nv}} }
```

I'd like to create an index at `metadata.known` field.

The problem is, since this field is not set a a java bean field, I'm not able to annotated it as `@Indexed`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, why don't you split the `metadata Object` in two?

One for known fields that you can index and other for the unknown that you cannot index. For example:

```
@Document
public class Metadata {

  @Indexed
  private String user;

  @Indexed
  private Object knownMetadata;

  private Object unknownMetadata;

}
```

As a result you will have something similar to:

```
{ user: user, knownMetadata: {knownField1: v, knownField2: nv}, unknownMetadata: {unknownField1: v, unknownField2: nv}} }
```

Comment: Are All `knownMetadata` sub-fields indexed?

Comment: Not sure about that, how many known fields you have in the metadata? I'm asking because you can always create a an @Indexed field for each known parameter and keep the unknown in the metadataObject

Answer (score 0):

For known fields you can create an index with the compound index annotation. It does not actually force you to have a compound index.

Consider this bean:

```
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name="my_index", def = "{'metadata.known' : 1}", background=true),
})
@Document
@Document
public class Metadata {

    @Indexed
    private String user;

    private Object metadata;
}
```

This would now create an index on the field: `metadata.known` - you can do this on any of the known fields and define them in the annotation.